# Unable to instantiate Scanner class - Hibernate 3.x deployment fails with WildFly

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, wildfly

I have a legacy Ear-Project that used Hibernate 3.6.6.Final (from JBoss6).
Now I would like to deploy that Ear into Wildfly 8.0.0.Final.

I did everything mentioned here: [Sharing the Hibernate 3.5 or greater JPA persistence provider between multiple applications](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-SharingtheHibernate3.5orgreaterJPApersistenceproviderbetweenmultipleapplications)

My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="pu">
        <description></description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/OracleDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:3" />
            <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name" value="hibernate/HelperSessionFactory" />
            <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name_is_jndi" value="true" /> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I added `Dependencies: org.hibernate:3` to the `MANIFEST.MF`

But the Deployment fails with the following error:

```
17:03:13,125 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."HelperEJB.ear/HelperEJB.jar#pu": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."HelperEJB.ear/HelperEJB.jar#pu": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: pu] Unable to instantiate Scanner class: class org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate3.HibernateAnnotationScanner
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:474)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: pu] Unable to instantiate Scanner class: class org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate3.HibernateAnnotationScanner
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1225)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.locateOrBuildScanner(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:767)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.scan(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:720)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:219)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:45)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:57)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:150)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:67) [hibernate-entitymanager.jar:3.6.6.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:318) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$1100(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:67) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:167) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate3.HibernateAnnotationScanner cannot be cast to org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.Scanner
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.locateOrBuildScanner(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:764)
        ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott Marlow opened a Bug for this. [WFLY-3074](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3074)

Workaround is to bundle Hibernate 3 jars with application.